# How to mount usb pendrive in ubuntu 8.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-8.04

I have ubuntu 8.04 and its not taking any pendrive and writing in the message box that 
"could'n mount the 4GB drive "
its shown in the Computer but i am unable to open it 
please give me a code or any kind of easy help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should find the device name by using the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

this will list the devices attached to your computer

then use this command to mount the pendrive :

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1
```

assuming that the device is sdb1 and it's formatted as FAT

source :

[Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=145135)